# JAXWS - Best Way to transfer file is byte[] or MTOM

Tags: arrays, jax-ws, mtom

I am trying to find best way to transfer files in JAXWS webservice.
MTOM or byte[] are the options I found. Someone can tell me which is the best way and why

Answer (score 1):

There's not a universal best way to transfer files. It depends on your needs.

#### As a byte array (Base64)

You should refer to it as Base64 encoded and not as `byte[]` (the file is sent as text using Base64 encoding and you will handle it in your java code as a `byte[]`). This method is fast since it only needs to encode the data to Base64 text and write it to the soap message, but the encoded data is 33% larger than the original file size.
So this method is only recommended for **small** files.

#### Using MTOM

This is the recommended method for **bigger** files because it does not increase the file size since it doesn't send the file as encoded data but as a MIME attachment. This method involves some steps more than just encoding the data so it takes a little more processing time although the difference may not be that big.

#### Best of both worlds

Most web services frameworks allow you to specify a *threshold* that indicates the minimum file size needed to use MTOM. If the file does not reach that size, the data will be sent as Base64 encoded text.

Example in JAX-WS:

```
@WebService
@MTOM(threshold = 3072)
public class MyWebService {
}
```

This means that if the file is less than 3 Mb it will be sent as Base64 text, and if it's bigger it will be sent using MTOM. This is a very common approach and it will probably suit your needs.

For a file to be considered small or big it depends on your hardware, concurrent clients using the service, etc.